# Is there a DIY, easy way of getting rid of tree stumps?

Tags: trees, tree-removal, stump-removal

In one edge of our garden, we had a few trees. They were getting big and pushing the fence, so we cut them down.

I want to plant some shrubs ..etc in their place, but I currently have this:

[image: one tree stump]

Here are some more:

[image: a few more tree stumps]

Is there an easy way of removing these so that I can plant something else in their place? The roots go deep!

Comment: Cedars are easy to pop out with a shovel but lilacs can need a truck and chain.  What were these?

Comment: The stump in the first photo is still alive and has already re-sprouted. You either have to totally remove the crown and the attached roots or use stump and brush killler on it.

Comment: Easiest way? Pay someone who can do stump removal. :) Otherwise, there are some chemical treatments that might work. Potassium nitrate (saltpetre) is a common chemical treatment for stump removal.

Comment: I have had several large trees removed , I get them cut as close to the ground as possible . Even dig out soil so they can be cut below soil level . Drill some large holes ( such as 1 " ) , pour in liquid fertilizer and bury or make hills over them . I am in zone 8 so it is warm enough that wood rot is active  most of the year. Also plant stuff to hide them.

Comment: @blacksmith37 any particular brand of liquid fertilizer? And how long does it take for the stump to fully rot and disappear? I also heard some people drill holes and put cooking oil in the holes, then set the stump on fire!

Answer (score 1):

Depends how fit you are. Use a mattock (looks like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Mighty-Mattock-Steel-Fibreglass-Handle/dp/B0765Y8H7B/ref=asc_df_B0765Y8H7B/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=309874391644&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=10499336050297573786&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1006764&hvtargid=pla-699859938948&psc=1)) and a strong border fork and spade. The best way you can, dig a nice big hole around each stump and hack through the roots using good overhead swings of the mattock. Take your time and be careful you don't hurt yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to remove those stumps by using farm jack and chain. It helps to make wooden support to stabilize jack, attach one end of chain to jack and other end of chain wrap around stump. Start pulling and if necessary cut bigger roots to make it easier to remove. After removing stump dig and remove smaller roots left in the ground.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=FoF3U8EEe4E

https://youtu.be/lTvwZAxG790

Comment: That is pretty cool! Are these things one can rent? Or must I buy one?